# React Testing Library: how to test a method on a parent component that is called from a child

Tags: reactjs, recaptcha, react-testing-library

I'm updating an app that was originally built in React 16 and all tests created with enzyme. I have updated to React 17 and am rewriting all tests using React testing library. I'm having trouble figuring out how to test methods on a parent or grandparent component when the method is called in the child/grandchild.

The structure looks like

`App` => `SubmissionForm` => `Tab1` (it's a multi-tabbed form and each tab is a separate component)

When the user clicks 'submit' on `Tab1`, it calls a series of methods on `SubmissionForm`, ending in `verifyRecaptchaScore`.

`verifyRecaptchaScore` calls `execute` from the package `react-google-invisible-recaptcha`, which calls the callback `onResolved`. Both the `Recaptcha` component and the `onResolved` callback are on the `App` component.

```
(App.js)

...

  async onResolved() {
    const token = await this.recaptcha.current.getResponse();
    this.props.apiSubmission.handleInput({
      target: { name: "reCaptchaValue", value: token }
    });
  }


...

<Recaptcha
   ref={refCaptcha}
   sitekey={sitekey}
   onResolved={this.onResolved}
/>
```

I'm trying to write tests for the methods on the `App` component. In the old app structure, using enzyme, I was able to test the `onResolved` method by just calling it programmatically in the test, using `wrapper.instance().onResolved()`

some relevant excerpts of the old test below:

```
...

const unconnectedSetup = async () => {
  const setupProps = { ...defaultProps };
  return shallow(<AppUnconnected {...setupProps} />);
};

...

describe("<App />", () => {
  ...

  describe("Misc methods", () => {
    it("onResolved calls recaptcha.getResponse and saves recaptcha token to redux store", async () => {
      wrapper = await unconnectedSetup();
      getResponseMock = jest
        .fn()
        .mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve("token"));
      wrapper.instance().recaptcha = {
        getResponse: getResponseMock
      };
      await wrapper.update();
      await wrapper.instance().onResolved();
      expect(getResponseMock.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
      await getResponseMock().then(() => {
        expect(handleInputMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
          target: { name: "reCaptchaValue", value: "token" }
        });
      });
    });
    ...
  });
```

With React testing library, I understand that I'm supposed to try to mimic the user experience rather than call methods programmatically. Which would mean something like:

- Load `App`
- User clicks `Next` button to load `Tab1`
- User clicks `Submit` button on Tab1 which triggers the chain of methods that eventually calls `onResolved`

but I can't get this to work. I'm able to simulate the user click that loads `Tab1` but when I try to simulate a user click on the `Submit` button on that tab I can't get it to call any of the other methods, and I'm struggling to even figure out where or how it's failing.

I have tried both
`userEvent.click(submitButton);`
and
`fireEvent.submit(tab1Form);`

but neither one seems to work.

Code that's not working:

```
describe("Misc methods", () => {
    it("onResolved calls recaptcha.getResponse and saves recaptcha token to redux store", async () => {
      getResponseMock = jest
        .fn()
        .mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve("token"));

      const props = {
        recaptcha: {
          current: {
            getResponseMock
          }
        },
        formValues: {
          ...generateSubmissionBody
        }
      };

      // simulate user click 'Next'
      const user = userEvent.setup();
      const { getByTestId, getByRole } = await setup({ ...props });
      const nextButton = getByTestId("button-next");
      await userEvent.click(nextButton);

      // check that tab 1 renders after clicking 'Next'
      const tab1Form = getByRole("form");
      await waitFor(() => {
        expect(tab1Form).toBeInTheDocument();
      });

      // simulate submit with default formValues
      const submitButton = getByTestId("button-submit");

      await waitFor(() => {
        userEvent.click(submitButton);
        // have also tried fireEvent.submit(tab1Form);
      });

      // expect the mock to have been called once
      await waitFor(() => {
        expect(getResponseMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
      });

      // the above test fails; mock is not called.

      // restore mock
      getResponseMock.mockRestore();
    });
```

Is this even the right approach for testing this method? If the method is on `App` but is triggered from `Tab1` does anybody have any better suggestions for how to test this? Or how to test a recaptcha callback in general?

If this is the right approach, any suggestions for how to troubleshoot why none of the intermediate methods (or `onResolved`) are being called when I simulate the user click on `Submit`? When I try this:

```
 const handleSubmit = jest.fn();
 tab1Form.onsubmit = handleSubmit;

 // simulate submit with default formValues
 await waitFor(() => {
   fireEvent.submit(tab1Form);
   expect(handleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();
 });
```

the test passes, so I know that `fireEvent.submit()` is simulating the submission; i just can't get it to work with the real methods that it's supposed to call onSubmit.